# Bounty Award button misaligned

Tags: bug, design

Creating my first bounty on SE today, I noticed that the Bounty Award Button is slightly misaligned. Maybe I'm just OCD about it but I think it should be fixed. Just centered and a nice space between the downvote button.

[image: Img]
[image: Img2]

Comment: oh wow. good eye.